# OS X app store builds are breaking the UI?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

We have run into an issue with submitting a build to the Max App store. When running directly from Xcode or making a non app store signed archive everything is perfect (we have tested the build on ~20 computers at this point, with various hardware and OS versions). However when we make an app store build and submit it for review, the review team encounters a broken UI in many places. The ONLY difference that we have been able to find is the signing of the build. We have also not been able to find a pattern of how things are breaking. Some elements disappear, some are moved around, some are perfectly fine.

An example:

Our builds - http://cl.ly/image/182f0H402x3Q

Review teams build during review - http://cl.ly/image/1P3y1P203825

We have been working with the DTS team at Apple - they have been very responsive but after several weeks are just as confused as we are. We have also filed this as a bug report and are awaiting a reply on that.

It seems that it is either something with the app store signing, or with how the review team re-signs the binary to test it. That process has not been made known to us but seems likely that it is the catalyst.

Has anyone run into this before? Any solutions? We have tried everything we can think of at this point and have hit a wall every time. Its been tweaked and submitted 5 times now, with the same result every time.